# Variables getting reinitialised when clicking on Button in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean

I am making an online form. I initialise 4 variables in my code at the beginning. When I select a dropdown, an event (DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged ) gets fired which in turn call Availability(). Here my boolean variable **avail_bus** is assigned a value. However, when i click on submit button ( Button1_Click1), the variable **avail_bus** is reinitialised to false. I debugged this and found out that upon clicking on Submit(Button1_Click1) the control first goes to the top of the code in the page which is

```
public partial class Appform : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private bool isNotDup = true;
        private bool avail_bus ;
        private int max_capacity_bus;
        private int realAvailability;
}
```

and then goes to **Button1_click1** .
How can I prevent this from happening ? If the state of avail_bus is changed to true while calling availability, it should not get reinitialized to true when i click on submit.

Below is my code :

```
namespace eTransport
{
    public partial class Appform : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private bool isNotDup = true;
        private bool avail_bus ;
        private int max_capacity_bus;
        private int realAvailability;

        protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindDropDown();


            }

        }

        //Method called when dropdown is selected in Bus Stop. It helps to populate Bus Number
        protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AutoPopulateBusStop();
            Availability();

        }


        //Method to load drop down values in Bus Stop. These are populated from database
        protected void BindDropDown ()
        {
           //some code here
        }

        //Method to autopopulate Bus Number based on selection of Bus Stop. The mapping is in the database in the table named -> dropdownlist
        protected void AutoPopulateBusStop ()
        {
            //some code here
        }


        protected void Availability ()
        {
            string constr5 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con5 = new SqlConnection(constr5))
            {
                try
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from etms where BusNo='" + TextBox6.Text.ToString() + "'"))
                    {
                        cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd5.Connection = con5;
                        con5.Open();
                        int capacity_from_db = Convert.ToInt16(cmd5.ExecuteScalar());
                        realAvailability = max_capacity_bus - capacity_from_db;

                        if (realAvailability > 0)
                        {
                            avail_bus = true;
                            TextBox2.Text = realAvailability.ToString() + " seats available ";
                            TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000");

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            TextBox2.Text = "Seats Not available. Please choose another Stop";
                            TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff1919");
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }

            }

        }


        protected void Button1_Click1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (isNotDup)
            {
                if (avail_bus)
                {
                   // Submit the Form
                }
                else
                {
                    Label14.Text = "Bus Seats not available!";
                    Label15.Text = null;
                }
            }
        }



        protected void PhoneNumberValidatation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {

           //some code here



        }


         }
}
```

Comment: Please share also how the button is linked to the event `Button1_Click`.

Comment: Did you try to use static?

Comment: static is not the best solution. Use view state.

Comment: @Rakin can you explain why?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save & Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click1" OnClientClick="if (!validate()) { return false;};" Width="300px" />

Comment: @Rakin..If a variable is Static then only one instance of it will be created..and will be shared on application level..That means if a user sets it to true then it will be true for all other users..which is wrong..each user should have ability to set true or false only for him or her not globally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible solution for this question.

[Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) - This will create one instance that accessible to all pages *(Global)*.

```
private static avail_bus = true;
```

[Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) - This enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates.

```
// Get...
private bool avail_bus = (bool)Session["avail_bus"];
// Set
Session["avail_bus"] = true;
```

[Control.ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx) - Gets a dictionary of state information that allows you to save and restore the view state of a server control across multiple requests for the same page.

```
public bool avail_bus
{
    get { return  ViewState["avail_bus"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["avail_bus"]; }
    set { ViewState["avail_bus"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Never use static variables in asp.net since they are shared across sessions and users.

Comment: No. Use server variables for statics. Session variables for user static fields. Viewstate or hidden fields for the rest.

Comment: Would using Hidden field be the best solution ?

Comment: @Azfar It's more secure to use Session instead of Hidden Fields because Session will only show a random cookie.

Comment: using Static is a problem. It would set the bool same for multiple users. @ Leonel

Comment: @Azfar Yup, so I suggest use Session instead.

Answer (score 1):

Every time there is a request for your page, a new instance of that page-class is created to handle that request. So any fields are re-initialized.

You can store a value in ViewState to remember a value over various requests:

```
namespace eTransport
{
    public partial class Appform : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
private bool isNotDup 
{
   set { ViewState["isNotDup "] = value; }
   get 
   {
      if (ViewState["isNotDup "] == null)
         return true;
      return (bool )ViewState["isNotDup "];
   }
}
private bool avail_bus 
{
   set { ViewState["avail_bus"] = value; }
   get 
   {
      if (ViewState["avail_bus"] == null)
         return true;
      return (bool )ViewState["avail_bus"];
   }
}
private int max_capacity_bus 
{
   set { ViewState["max_capacity_bus "] = value; }
   get 
   {
      if (ViewState["max_capacity_bus "] == null)
         return 0;
      return (int)ViewState["max_capacity_bus "];
   }
}
private int realAvailability
{
   set { ViewState["realAvailability"] = value; }
   get 
   {
      if (ViewState["realAvailability"] == null)
         return 0;
      return (int)ViewState["realAvailability"];
   }
}
    protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindDropDown();


            }

        }

        //Method called when dropdown is selected in Bus Stop. It helps to populate Bus Number
        protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AutoPopulateBusStop();
            Availability();

        }


        //Method to load drop down values in Bus Stop. These are populated from database
        protected void BindDropDown ()
        {
           //some code here
        }

        //Method to autopopulate Bus Number based on selection of Bus Stop. The mapping is in the database in the table named -> dropdownlist
        protected void AutoPopulateBusStop ()
        {
            //some code here
        }


        protected void Availability ()
        {
            string constr5 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con5 = new SqlConnection(constr5))
            {
                try
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from etms where BusNo='" + TextBox6.Text.ToString() + "'"))
                    {
                        cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd5.Connection = con5;
                        con5.Open();
                        int capacity_from_db = Convert.ToInt16(cmd5.ExecuteScalar());
                        realAvailability = max_capacity_bus - capacity_from_db;

                        if (realAvailability > 0)
                        {
                            avail_bus = true;
                            TextBox2.Text = realAvailability.ToString() + " seats available ";
                            TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000");

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            TextBox2.Text = "Seats Not available. Please choose another Stop";
                            TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff1919");
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }

            }

        }


        protected void Button1_Click1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (isNotDup)
            {
                if (avail_bus)
                {
                   // Submit the Form
                }
                else
                {
                    Label14.Text = "Bus Seats not available!";
                    Label15.Text = null;
                }
            }
        }



        protected void PhoneNumberValidatation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {

           //some code here



        }


         }
}
```

Comment: ViewState already has its down-side and lot of stuff to carry. Why not simply use *HiddenField*. That is what they are for.

Comment: @vnikhil You do realise that too becomes part of the view state?

Comment: View state is secure. Hidden field is insecure View state store large amount of data .Hidden field will store small amount of data.

Comment: @hvd - They are separate! Otherwise hidden fields would not work if you turned off viewstate at page level. Also, ViewState takes a form of hidden fields once page is rendered and has encoded content, which is not a case with <asp:HiddenField../> which shows you the stored content in human-readable format. Please clarify if I am going in a wrong direction.

Comment: @Rakin - Agreed. OP wants to store only *avail_bus* variable value.

Comment: @vnikhil: Thats true... ;)

Comment: @vnikhil They render both in the view state and as input elements. Try with `Visible="false"`: no input element, but it still works.

Comment: Hope Azfar got solution?

Comment: So, should i use hidden fields ?

Comment: Which one will be the best way ? and why ? Thanks

Comment: In this case both are identical.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will do it and let you guys know

Answer (score 1):

You can store the availability status in a hidden input field which later gets posted on Button1 click event.

And in button1 click event instead of accessing the avail value from variable access it from hiddenField's value

Another option would be calling Availability() again in click event of button1 as a first line so that it sets proper value in the avail_bus variable